# Fill blank cells in one google table with data from another table

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to combine two tables in google sheets that don't have the same number of lines and not the same order. Is this possible?

I have this table where I need to add "home rank" and "away rank" for several hundred lines. The table has four columns:

**Home Team**   **Away Team**   **Home Rank**   **Away Rank**

Bayern  Bremen
E. Frankfurt    Schalke
Augsburg    Wolfsburg
HSV Ingolstadt

Since the rank of one team doesn't change I'd like to automatically add the rank from a second table that simply reads:

**Rank**    **Team**

1   Bayern

2   Leipzig

3   Dortmund

Any help appreciated, thanks alot
Batis

Comment: I figured out that a SVERWEIS could work. Problem is that for some fields the wrong rank is added, e.g. instead of taking an "8" from the rank table a "1" is added (means that several teams have rank 1 what is impossible). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got it and found the solution myself.

You have to add "false" as a fourth parameter to the vlookup-formula to avoid incorrect values.

Sorry for posting the question before trying slookup (sverweis in German).

Batis